# Excel VBA: Copy a single row into another worksheet while the copying offsets down by one each time

Tags: excel, vba

Total noob at this as I just started learning VBA today. I've essentially just been following this guy's instructions which has worked wonders: www.excelcampus.com/vba/copy-paste-another-workbook/. However, now I want to do this in reverse. So that means copying "A2:IG2" from Sheet1 and pasting it to "A2:IG2" Sheet2 and then copying "A3:IG3" and pasting it to "A2:IG2" Sheet2. I want to keep this on loop until I've copied all the values from Sheet1.

```
Sub Copy_Paste_Below_Last_Cell()
'Find the last used row in both sheets and copy and paste data below existing data.

  'Open method requires full file path to be referenced.
  Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive\Desktop\Sheet2.xlsx"

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long

  'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
  Set wsCopy = Workbooks("Sheet2.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet2")
  Set wsDest = Workbooks("Sheet1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")

  '1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column A
  lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

  '2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column A
  'Offset property moves down 1 row
  lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

  '3. Copy & Paste Data
  wsCopy.Range("A2:IG2" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
    wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)
  Workbooks("Sheet2").Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

The code above is a modified version which I thought would work but instead of copying "A2:IG2" specifically, it copies all available date on the range A:IG and the offset row.

Comment: you want to continue the loop till when ? or what condition ? Please edit the question and add the description of the specific problem.

Comment: FYI It's a tad confusing to have a *Workbook* named `Sheet1`/`Sheet2`...

Comment: Please clarify, Are you trying over write the range in sheet2? like you state in your question... `copying "A2:IG2" from Sheet1 and pasting it to "A2:IG2" Sheet2 and then copying "A3:IG3" and pasting it to "A2:IG2" Sheet2.`, Or are you trying to copy multiple rows in sheet1 and paste them to sheet2?

Comment: @BruceWayne- sorry haha.

Comment: @GMalc- No, its not multiple rows. Just one row. You see after it copies the row from Sheet1, the workbook Sheet2 closes. I use the copied row on Sheet2 to load it onto a separate third party program then I load up the code again which opens Sheet2 to have the next row of data from Sheet1 to be copied.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the last part

```
'3. Copy & Paste Data
wsCopy.Range("A2:IG2").Copy _
wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow + 1)
Workbooks("Sheet2").Close SaveChanges:=True
```

Comment: Hm, it did copy what I want initially but it doesn't offset to the lower row afterwards. I mean all that was changed was the lCopyLastRow. Still though thanks and I think I'll try and work around this.

Comment: Um I meant offset to the lower row afterwards after copying from the copy range on Sheet1, your edit offsets on the destination on Sheet2 instead. I'll experiment though and see where it goes haha

Comment: Your code is doing nothing, for now, after pasting, so why do You need to go offset on sheet1? I added +1 to Sheet2 destination to paste values in first empty cells :)

Comment: Well its a long story. You see, I need Sheet2 for a program (let's call it SM) and it only needs that single row of data so there's no to offset it on the destination. So after I paste the data from Sheet1 to Sheet2 I use SM to utilize the pasted data, then afterwards I would need the next row below from Sheet1 which is why I'd need the selection to offset so I can just kinda automate the process a bit.

Comment: First of all, i just found out that You've mistaken last row formulas, right order should be:
lCopyLastRow --> wsDest
lDestLastRow --> wsCopy
based on your variables description.
Still knowing range A2:IG2 next row is 3, so its easy, if You wanna do a loop just do "A2:IG"&i or "A"& i & ":IG" & i